# Mesh network 802.11s vs adhoc

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, ad-hoc-wireless, mesh

What is the difference between 802.11s and adhoc?

Is it compulsory to have same channel for wireless mesh node or it can have created using different channels where neighbouring nodes on on 2 non overlapping channel?

If it can be done which one should be used 802.11s , adhoc or something else?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major difference is that in a mesh network, nodes forward between other nodes. In a  simple ad-hoc network, nodes must see each other to communicate.

In either network, a node can use multiple radios for multiple channels and even forward between them in a mesh. Nodes must be on the same channel in order to transmit to each other.